# Showing that $\{ 1, \cos t, \cos^2 t, \dots, \cos^6 t \}$ is a linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is:

> Show that $\{ 1, \cos t, \cos^2 t, \dots, \cos^6 t \}$ is a linearly independent set of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

The problem expects the student to use a computer program such as Matlab.

To solve the problem I created a matrix in Matlab with $t$ ranging from $1$ to $7$, then row reduced it and got the identity matrix as result. I.e. the columns of the matrix is linearly independent.

Is it enough to just show for $t=1\to 7$; could it not possibly break down at some other number? And is there a more elegant way of solving this without the use of "brute force"?

Here's the Matlab code if necessary:

```
for t = 1:7
A(t,:) = [1 cos(t) (cos(t))^2 (cos(t))^3 (cos(t))^4 (cos(t))^5 (cos(t))^6];
end
```

Comment: It **will** break down at some other numbers (extreme example $t=\pi, 2\pi, \dots, 7\pi$, but there are more subtle ones).  But if you can find *some* collection of seven $t$'s, that settles it. There is a much easier (for me) way that involves no Matlab.

Comment: Simply composing each of the functions with $\cos^{-1}$ on the right gives 7 polynomials on [-1,1], which must be independent because they have different degree. Since function composition preserves linear combinations, the original functions must also be independent.

Comment: Those polynomials Henning is referring to are termed *Chebyshev polynomials*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The computational approach that you used works well.  For our particular collection of functions, or more generally for the *powers* of a single function $f(t)$, there is a straightforward non-computational approach.  As a bonus, the argument below works just as well for $666$ as it does for $6$.

Suppose to the contrary that our collection $\{1,\cos t, \cos^2 t, \dots, \cos^6 t\}$ of functions is not linearly independent.  Then there are constants $a_0, a_1, \dots, a_6$, not all $0$, such that 
$$a_0+a_1 \cos t +a_2 \cos^2 t +\cdots +a_6 \cos^6 t=0 \quad\text{ for all $t$}.$$

Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots +a_6x^6$. Not all the coefficients $a_i$ are $0$, so the equation $P(x)=0$ has at most $6$ solutions. (A non-zero polynomial of degree $\le n$ has at most $n$ roots.)  Thus if we can show that the function $\cos t$ can take on more than $6$ different values, we obtain the desired contradiction.

But $\cos t$ takes on infinitely many different values as $t$ ranges over the reals, or indeed over any interval of non-zero length.  This completes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, André! Forgive me for asking, but it is not obvious to me why the fact that $\cos t$ can take on more than 6 different values makes a contradiction?

Comment: We are supposing that there are $a_i$ not all $0$ such that $P(\cos t)=0$, where $P(x)$ is the polynomial of my post.  Since $\cos t$ can take on more than $6$ values, that would mean that $P(x)$ would be $0$ at more than $6$ places. But a non-zero polynomial of degree $\le 6$ can be $0$ at at most $6$ places.  The only way out is to conclude that $a_i=0$ for all $i$, meaning that your $7$ functions are linearly independent.  For the same reason, $1$, $\tan t$, $\tan^2 t$, and so on up to $\tan^{101} t$ is a linearly independent collection.

Answer (score 6):

Two comments:

1. Suppose that you have functions $f_1(t)$, $f_2(t),\ldots,f_k(t)$, and that they are linearly **dependent** in the vector space of all real-valued functions. That means that you can find real numbers $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$ such that
   $$\alpha_1 f_1(t)+\cdots + \alpha_k f_k(t) = 0.$$
   That means that for any value $a$ of $t$, you will have
   $$\alpha_1f_1(a) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(a) = 0.$$
   In particular, if you pick $k$ different values for $t$, $a_1,\ldots,a_k$, then you have:
   $$\begin{align*}
   \alpha_1f_1(a_1) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(a_1) &= 0\\
   \alpha_1f_1(a_2) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(a_2) &= 0\\
   &\cdots\\
   \alpha_1f_1(a_k) + \cdots + \alpha_k f_k(a_k) &= 0
   \end{align*}$$
   which in turn means that:
   $$\alpha_1 \left(\begin{array}{c}f_1(a_1)\\f_1(a_2)\\ \vdots \\ f_1(a_k)\end{array}\right)
   +\alpha_2\left(\begin{array}{c}f_2(a_1)\\f_2(a_2)\\\vdots\\f_2(a_k)\end{array}\right) + \cdots + \alpha_k\left(\begin{array}{c}f_k(a_1)\\f_k(a_2)\\\vdots\\f_k(a_k)\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{array}\right),$$
   so the columns of the corresponding matrix are linearly dependent, so the corresponding matrix is singular.

   By contrapositive, if the matrix you get by evaluating the functions at $k$ different points as you did is **nonsingular**, then the functions have to be linearly **independent**, as you conclude.

   *However*, the converse is not true: it may be that you get "unlucky" and evaluate at points where the matrix is singular, even if the functions are not. If instead of using $t=1,2,\ldots,7$ you had used $t=\pi,2\pi,\ldots,7\pi$, your matrix would have been singular, even though the functions are, as you concluded, linearly independent. So the matrix being nonsingular is **sufficient**, but it is not *necessary* for the functions to be linearly independent.
2. As to other methods of doing this... (comment two): the standard way when your functions can be differentiated enough times (as they can be here), is to use the [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian).

Comment: Of course, compute the Wronskian.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Arturo! I think my problem might stem from a misunderstanding of what linear independence requires. I thought for functions to be linearly independent, they need to be so for all $\mathbb{R}$; however, it seems like it's the other way around: i.e. if a set of functions are not linearly dependent for all $\mathbb{R}$, then they are linearly independent. So if we can show *one* example of linear independence, then we're done. Is that the gist of what you were saying?

Comment: @Jodles: I honestly don't understand your comment. By definition, there are only two possibilities for any set of vectors: either they are linearly independent, or they are linearly dependent. It is *always* the case that if a set of vectors is not linearly dependent, then it is linearly independent; and that if it is not linearly independent, then  it is linearly dependent. For functions, equality means equality *as functions*, so when we write that $a_1f_1(t)+\cdots+a_nf_n(t)=0$, we mean that this holds for *all* values of $t$.

Answer (score 3):

The equality 
$$
\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}
$$ 
shows that $(\cos x)^n$, being a polynomial of degree $n$ in $e^{ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$, is **not** a linear combination of lower powers of $\cos x$.

The fact (implicitly used) that the functions $e^{inx}$ are linearly independent follows from the equality 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ e^{inx}=in\ e^{inx}. 
$$

Answer (score 1):

The system of functions $f_i,i=1,2,...,n$ is linearly independent on some set $A$ iff the condition

> $\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \displaystyle \sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i f_i(x) = 0$ *for all* $x\in A$

is satisfied only for $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i=1,...,n$. So, you should solve as many equations, as there are elements in $A$. On the other hand, it's sufficient to take just some elements from $A$ to show that
$$
\sum\limits_{i}\alpha_i f_i(x_j) = 0
$$
for all $j=1,...,m$ implies that $\alpha_i = 0$ for all $i$.

I would say that in your case it's sufficient to consider $8$ points $x_j$ to obtain the over-determined system of linear equations on $\alpha_i$ since $n=7$ in your case and to obtain the over-determined system *usually* it is sufficient to have $n+1$ equation.