# How to show that $\{t, \sin t , \cos 2 t , \sin t \cos t \}$ is a linearly independent set of functions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I have this homework question that I have no idea how to do:

> Show that $\{t, \sin(t), \cos(2t), \sin(t)\cos(t) \}$ is a linearly independent set of functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Start by assuming that
>   $$c_1 t + c_2 \sin(t) + c_3 \cos(2t) + c_4 \sin(t)\cos(t) = 0$$
>   for all $t$. Choose specific values of $t$ ($t=0, 1, 2\dots$) until you get a system with enough equations to determine that all the $c_i$'s must be $0$.

My only guess is to set up a matrix based on this polynomial somehow, then row reduce it to find the pivot columns. Subbing in different $t$'s would allow for some value to be attached to each $c$. Would that be the matrix? Shouldn't it be formed by the $c$ values?

Comment: I would choose specific values *from the unit circle* for $t$...

Comment: What does choosing values for t do for you though? Is the matrix formed by the t terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing that $\{ 1, \cos t, \cos^2 t, \dots, \cos^6 t \}$ is a linearly independent set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70920/showing-that-1-cos-t-cos2-t-dots-cos6-t-is-a-linearly-independ)

Comment: @Gortaur, I wouldn't say this question is a duplicate of that one, but I would certainly recommend that Randy have a look at the older question, as much of what is there is directly relevant to Randy's needs.

Comment: Evaluate at four points. If you are not unlucky,  you will get $4$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$. Maybe try (i) $t=0$; (ii) $t=2\pi$; (iii) $t=\pi/2$; (iv) $t=\pi/4$. Look at the question referenced by @Gortaur. There are ways other than evaluating.

Comment: Since this equation should hold for **all** values of $t$, we can pick "convenient" values! For instance, with $t = 0$, we get (since sin(o) = 0) that $c_3 = 0$ right away. Then you can take the derivative (as has been mentioned in Mr. Cook's answer) and set t = 0 again. Or try t = $\pi / 2$, etc

Comment: that link helped. thanks guys!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: The unit circle contains uncountably many points.  I don't see how that helps narrow it down. (Of course there are specific points on the unit circle that are helpful to consider, like the right, top, left, bottom, maybe northeast.)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you plug-in $t=t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$ then you'll have

$$\begin{array}{cc}
   c_1 t_1 + c_2\sin(t_1)+c_3 \cos(2t_1)+c_4\sin(t_1)\cos(t_1) & =0 \\
   c_1 t_2 + c_2\sin(t_2)+c_3 \cos(2t_2)+c_4\sin(t_2)\cos(t_2) & =0 \\
   c_1 t_3 + c_2\sin(t_3)+c_3 \cos(2t_3)+c_4\sin(t_3)\cos(t_3) & =0 \\   
   c_1 t_4 + c_2\sin(t_4)+c_3 \cos(2t_4)+c_4\sin(t_4)\cos(t_4) & =0 \end{array}$$

and so the corresponding matrix equation is

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
   t_1 & \sin(t_1) & \cos(2t_1) &\sin(t_1)\cos(t_1)  \\
   t_2 & \sin(t_2) & \cos(2t_2) &\sin(t_2)\cos(t_2)  \\
   t_3 & \sin(t_3) & \cos(2t_3) &\sin(t_3)\cos(t_3)  \\   
   t_4 & \sin(t_4) & \cos(2t_4) &\sin(t_4)\cos(t_4)  \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} c_1\\ c_2\\ c_3\\ c_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

By choosing the "right" values for $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4$ you'll have a matrix which is invertible (so $c_1=c_2=c_3=c_4=0$ is the only solution). You can check this is case by making sure the determinant is non-zero. [I believe the values $t_1=0$, $t_2=1$, $t_3=2$, $t_4=3$ work, but it is not pretty.]

An alternate approach is to differentiate your equation 3 times and then plug-in a single value (like $t=0$). In this case, the coefficient matrix you'll end up with is called a [Wronskian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian). If it's determinant is non-zero, then the matrix is invertible so the corresponding system only has the trivial solution and hence your functions are linearly independent.

Comment: What about $$sin2t = 2sint . cost$$ => 2nd and 4th functions are linearly dependent. So the set is not a linearly dependent set. [Idea credit: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/in-the-vector-space-of-all-real-valued-functions-find-a-basis-for-the-subspace-spanned-by/ ]

Comment: If it was sin(2t), it would be dependent. However, it's sin(t). You could replace the last column with 0.5sin(2t). But sin(kt) and sin(mt) are independent when k and m have different magnitudes.

Comment: My bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For instance, if you let $t=0$ then $t=0$, $\sin(0)=0$, and $\sin(0)\cos(0)=0$.  But, $\cos(2\cdot 0)=\cos(0)=1$ and your equation becomes $c_3=0$.  As The Chaz suggested, you might want to try values from the unit circle where you know the various function values of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 0):

At $t = 0$  we have
$t = 0, \sin(t) = 0,\,\cos(2t) = 1$ and $\sin(t)\cos(t) = 0$. So if I choose $c_3 = 0$ and allow  $c_1, c_2, c_4$ to take any other value, $$c_1 t + c_2 \sin(t) + c_3 \cos(2t) + c_4 \sin(t)\cos(t) = 0$$ is satisfied at $t = 0$. I think that implies that the functions are linearly dependent at $t = 0$. This would hold true for $t = k\pi$.