# Verification of a proof about when a polynomial is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, induction

I was doing an exercise about algebraic geometry and, the final step is to prove that if the polynomial in $k[t]$ ($k$ a field) $\sum_{i=0}^na_i(1-t^2)^i(1+t^2)^{n-i}=0$ then, the coefficients $a_i$ must all be zero.

It's true for $n=0,1,2$, I tested it while trying to write a proof.

Let's assume that it's true for $n-1$. That is, if the polynomial of degree $n-1$ is zero,  then all its coefficients are of degree zero.

One can construct the polynomial of degree $n$ like this: $p_{n-1}\cdot(1+t^2)+a_n(1+t^2)^n$.

If that is zero, then we can write $p_{n-1}\cdot(1+t^2)=-a_n(1+t^2)^n$.

Now the confusing part. I have to deduce that all coefficients are zero. If I put $t=0$, then $p_{n-1}=-a_n$. But $p_{n-1}$ was zero, so $a_n$ is zero, and therefore all of them are zero.

Is this correct? It's the final step of a problem and induction is not among my most effective proof tricks...

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks!

Comment: What were the previous questions? This might help to solve this one, which you say is the last one of a problem.

Comment: If $\operatorname{char}k=2$, $1-t^2=1+t^2$ and there exist a lot of easy counterexamples.

Comment: Your argument is not correct. Because we were given $p_n=0$ and we need to use if $p_{n-1}=0$ all $a_i, i\geq n-1$ are zeros. If you want to use induction first you need to show if $p_n=0$ then $a_n=0$ so we can use our induction statement

Answer (score 1):

In the case $k=\mathbb{R}$, we can set $t=\tan x$.

Using classical trigonometric identities:

$$1+\tan^2 x = \frac{1}{\cos^2 x} \ \ \text{and} \ \ 1-\tan^2 x = \frac{\cos (2x)}{\cos^2 x},$$

relationship:

$$\forall t, \ \ \ \sum_{i=0}^n a_i(1-t^2)^i(1+t^2)^{n-i}=0$$

is equivalent to

$$\forall x, \ \ \ \frac{1}{(\cos^2 x)^n} \sum_{i=0}^na_i(\cos 2x)^{i}=0$$

which amounts, up to an evident change of variables, to:

$$\forall x, \ \ \ \sum_{i=0}^na_i(\cos x)^{i}=0$$

which is possible if and only if the all the $a_i$ are zero because functions defined by $f_i(x)=(\cos x)^{i}$ are linearly independent (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/70933/305862)).